# RS-232 control for Advance Energy Pinnacle power supply

Tags: power-supply, rs232, automation

I am inspired to post this question and answer by [this meta post](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/seeding-er-with-some-high-level-electronics-questions).  This problem caused me a lot of problems and took a while to figure out.  I have a partial answer.  Perhaps others can elaborate based on their experiences.

I work for a small business and we have several [Pinnacle power supplies](http://www.advanced-energy.com/en/Pinnacle_Series.html) made by Advanced Energy.  We have recently been making a push to automate a number of our processes.  The hope is to control the power supplies from a computer via RS-232.  Are there any caveats to be aware of?

Comment: We had actually planned to not seed questions. I appreciate the question and information. The issue is that when you already know the answer most people will not take the time to answer it. This could also mean that we do not get better solutions for the answer. In general the process of seeding is not a great way to go about generating site content. HOWEVER, sharing your knowledge with us now and again is not harmful. Thank you for taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

First:  The supply must be capable of AEBus communication.  You can find out if this is the case via the debug menu from the front panel (if your supply has one), by opening up hyperterminal and trying to communicate with it, or, easiest of all, calling AE and giving them the serial number.  **NOTE:  The presence of a serial port on the back of the device *does not* necessarily mean that it is capable of serial communication!**

Second:  Even if the supply *is* AEBus capable, it may not be able to be set to every mode that one would be able to set from the front panel.  In my experience, the most significant example is:  **If your supply has a DeviceNet port, it will be impossible to set the supply into voltage regulation mode while controlling it with the serial port.**  In other words, if you have a DeviceNet supply and you want to control it via RS-232 for a voltage-controlled process, you're out of luck.  AE has confirmed that *no* DeviceNet enabled supplies support anything other than power-regulation while in host (i.e., RS-232) control mode.  Even though you can set it into this regulation mode while in local control.

Third:  There are several different flavors of serial connector that may be present on the back of the supply.  There's the so-called "standard serial port" which uses an RJ-11 type connector and (possibly present) AEBus ports which may be DB-9 or DB-25.  As far as I can tell, the only difference in communicating via the "standard" port versus the AEBus ports is the baud rate.  The standard port communicates at 19.2 kbaud whereas the AEBus ports communicate at 9200 baud.  The structure of the commands is identical.

On a final, semi-related note:  If you do have a DeviceNet supply and wish to not use it, you don't have to supply it with 24V just to avoid an error.  Open the supply up and remove the card.  You then have to switch a jumper (which would otherwise be jumpered on the exterior part of the DeviceNet card), whose identifier depends on the model of your supply.  Call AE and they'll tell you what its label is.  Problem solved! (Unless you also want to use voltage regulation via RS-232!)